# Is an imposed workflow of services call an antipattern?

Tags: anti-patterns, service

We have an application using a bunch of services. As soon as the application is launched it should call a webservice method, "RegisterMachineSession". In this method we accomplish some basic work that should be done before any other service call. For example, we load in memory a set of parameters associated with the machine session that should remain constant during the application usage.

I am asking myself if it is not a code smell because each service call should be independant. Is it a known antippatern or is it ok to this because we are needing a concept of session?

Comment: From a practical standpoint, the kind of isolation you describe doesn't really exist.  The vast majority of non-trivial services require some sort of connection authentication, and as soon as you do that, you're creating a *session.*

Comment: You are right but in our application we are using a session "in disguise" :  
  1) the application should first call the service method "RegisterMachineSession",                                                                    
 2) then we store a point in time in database and load a list of static parameter corresponding to this point in time.  We are not using any sort of authentification token or any sort authentication scheme...

Comment: Is it your assertion that your technique is a code smell because you are "disguising" it?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my answer to give more informations. I have a bad feeling that something is not good with our implementation. So I was making some research about that... But at the end of the day the application is working :-)

Comment: Isn't your "session" a way to centralized some common parameters ? Or does they may change depending on the client ?

Comment: @Walfrat : a client of my services should put orders based on prices as they were at the moment of the registerMachineSession call.  The client could then put order for weeks and at a certain point close the "session" : by this I mean that the next time the client want to put orders the prices could have changed... So the parameters or prices ar changing depending on client and time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you saying that it's not possible to have independent service calls with authentication?

Comment: @JimmyJames: No.  I'm saying that such calls always have some sort of *context,* even if it's just some state saved in a database somewhere.  Such state would be inevitably tied to some sort of "session" information (which would include the User ID from the authentication and some status information), even if that session is merely implied by the database state.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure what the scope of 'such calls' is but my team currently builds and maintains dozens of service operations with no state.  Authentication is also supported in this scheme.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Do you ever write to a database during 'such calls?'

Comment: @Dypso I'm baffled by this.  Why would you want the client to determine when they want new prices?  It would surely always be in their favor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey For those few calls which exist so that the client can create or update data: Yes.  For everything else: no.  There's a logging sink but nothing that we need to call to register or start a session or anything like that.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Fair enough. I'm always a bit skeptical when folks use words like "code smell" and "better way" in their questions without qualifying those terms, because it means they haven't thought out the implications of their design decisions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added what statelessness means in this context.  You seem to be referring to a more general concept of state which isn't incorrect, it's just not the problematic statefullness we wish to avoid in services.

Comment: Note that security measures often fly in the face of efficiency in an attempt to curb abuse (intentional or not, doesn't matter). No security measure has ever made things easier. Everything would be so much simpler (and neater) if we didn't need to secure ourselves from ill intentions. E.g. when I come home, it's easier to have the door already unlocked so I don't need to fidget with my keys. But you need to weigh the **gains** of doing so against the **losses** incurred by abuse. The question isn't if it's an antipattern, but rather whether it is **warranted**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an imposed workflow would imply that your services are not stateless.  Statefulness isn't necessarily an anti-pattern but it is undesirable as it makes scaling your design much more difficult.  [Statelessness](http://serviceorientation.com/serviceorientation/service_statelessness) in this context is the lack of server state between calls. If you move session state to a database, for example, it isn't considered stateful from a service perspective. If I make 3 calls, it shouldn't matter if they are satisfied by three different servers.  If you can eliminate sessions, that's even better but if not, moving them to a shared datastore eliminates most of the issues.

I'm not sure what to make of "For example, we load in memory a set of parameters associated with the machine session that should remain constant during the application usage."  Is this something that the client is providing or is it something server side is determining?

In the former case, can the client provide it on every call?  The extra overhead could very-well be worth the elimination of server-side state.  What prevents you from doing it when the first 'real' service is called?

Perhaps scaling and fault-tolerance are not of much importance here but making services stateless will greatly simplify the overall design.

Comment: "For example, we load in memory a set of parameters ..."  This operation is made on server side : data associated with client work is constant during what we call a session (could be 1 to day long).  In fact when loading those parameters we are also saving the state in database and returning a token to the client so it can refer on consecutive calls to his "session" data. We are fully able to scale on serveral server if necessary. It was the just the imposed workflow that seems weird to me. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: If it's required to call one service and use the response from that to call another service, that's pretty normal.  I would advise against very complex sequences of steps.  If you can I would store as much in the token as possible.  For example, if they retrieve a price list, you can encode their account, the time and the price list ID in the token and sign it.  If I understand, you are doing something along these lines which seems totally fine.  The concept behind this completely horrible acronym/initialism might be worth reading up on: [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)

Comment: I am not certain that this could be called a direct application of HATEOAS... If we were applying strict HATEOAS we would have enforce the workflow by sending back **explicitly** to the client on each call to a service the list of the various operations it could then access... So in my mind HATEOAS is when you have a dummy client and an explicit workflow given at runtime based on a peculiar state at this time (resource and client state, external condition)

Comment: @Dypso I pointed to that simply as food for thought.  I didn't mean to imply that this was what you were doing or that you should necessarily do it.  I apologize if my mentioning it created confusion.

Comment: No problem. I was aware about HATEOAS but it is always good to know about new things!

Answer (score 1):

You'll often see services do or return something necessary for a future call to the same service or to another.   For instance, I need to get a list of users by calling UserService and after some filters, I then call a second service OrdersService with a list of users.  In this there is absolutely nothing incorrect as each service is given exactly everything required to do its job with no state.

In your example however, it seems to me that the RegisterMachineSession is sort of opening a means to call other services, which is most certainly *not* stateless.  Generally if such a thing were to be done, you simply call the service you require and if necessary, the service *itself* will open this session to be used later.  This means making a service *stateful* in a sense, however, this is generally acceptable as it is handled internally and to the caller, the state is entirely transparent (caller should not care about whether or not a previous call has opened a session or otherwise).

So in my opinion, yes, it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: If there's no persisted state in-between your call to get users and placing an order, how can you be sure of the identity of the user placing the order?   What prevents a malicious user from placing an order under somebody else's identity?

Comment: @BenCottrell So create a third service which accepts credentials and returns a token to be passed to the other two services.  It would still be weak security without some sort of firewall enforcement.  The other two services remain stateless in this way.  But I see your point.  Not every service can be stateless, but that doesn't mean it should be *encouraged*.

Comment: @Neil : you got my point : the call to others service could not be made correctly if the first one to RegisterMachineSession is not done in first place.    I was thinking effectively to open a session if necessary and transparently as you said.